# CSS background repeat not working when called inside folder

Tags: html, css

I have a folder called projects on my desktop and inside the folder I have a file called index.html and a folder called images containing all the images. When I try to call the background: url("images/shadow1.PNG") repeat-y; it doesnt seem to work for some reason, anyone have any ideas why ?

If I put the documents on my desktop the index and images folder and try running the background: url(shadow1.PNG) repeat-y; it works just fine.

Hope that made sense, any information and code examples on how to fix this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference where the image file as long as it's addressed correctly. Please show more code. Also try confirming in Firebug whether a request to the PNG is made.

Comment: What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: Pekka has this right.  It's just a path issue.

Comment: Still cant get it to work, using firefox. Code example http://jsfiddle.net/4BDaP/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in css file change the  `background: url("images/shadow1.PNG")` to `background: url("../images/shadow1.PNG")`

It has to return to the root folder (projects) using `../` and then enter the image folder to find the image.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on Sotiris answer. The CSS 'locates' files starting from it's own location. This means you have to navigate to the image from the CSS' directory.

For example: your image reside in /trunk/images and the css in /files/css (I wouldn't suggest those folder names) you would have to go back 2 directories into the /trunk/images directory:

```
.something
{
    background: url(../../trunk/images/image.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```